# Android: CoordinatorLayout and SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-appcompat, swiperefreshlayout, coordinator-layout

I try to implement auto hiding toolbar feature from the new support library 22.2.0. Without SwipeRefreshLayout is working fine:

[image]

But when I re add this layout, toolbar **overlap** the recyclerview:

[image]

**Code:**

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cardList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2020 with Androidx:**

**Code:**

```xml
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cardList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Set the scroll behavior to the `SwipeRefreshLayout` not the `RecyclerView`.

```xml
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: @Tomas I would like to ask if you noticed, that if you start scrolling  until the AppBarLayout got fully expanded (verticalOffset reached 0) and you keep scrolling the SwipeRefreshLayout's refresh indicator appears, thus the user will be able to trigger this action as well. It's easy to reproduce at least on my side, having only a few elements on the RecyclerView. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsár see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779667/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-and-swiperefreshlayout-get-stuck#answer-30785823 work for me