# android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout does not swipe when inside a android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, coordinator-layout

The goal is to have a collapsing `toolbar` and a `SwipeRefreshLayout` which has items. To be able to use the support library, I use `CoordinatorLayout` which hosts an `AppBarLayout`. That `AppBarLayout` has a `toolbar` and `SwipeRefreshLayout` which has a grid view. Using `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` there is no problem with collapsing and opening the `toolbar`, however `SwipeRefreshLayout` does not swipe all the way down, i.e., it is stuck. When taking the `SwipeRefreshLayout` out of `AppBarLayout`, it scrolls fine but this time the toolbar does not collapse. below is the layout xml. any help is appreciated.

PS: I used [this link](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/) for collapsing toolbar implementation:

Here's my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                                                                     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                                       
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"                                                              
    android:layout_height="match_parent"                                                                             
    android:layout_width="match_parent">                                                                

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout                                                                      
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"                                                                               
        android:layout_width="match_parent"                                                                          
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">                                                                        

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar                                                                               
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"                                                                                    
            android:layout_width="match_parent"                                                                          
            android:layout_height="50dp"                                                                                 
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"                                                     
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"                                                                     
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">                                                                                                                                             
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>                                                                             

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout                                                                    
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                                   
            android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"                                                                               
            android:layout_width="match_parent"                                                                          
            android:layout_height="match_parent"                                                                         
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">                                                

            <GridView                                                                                                    
                android:id="@+id/gridview"                                                                               
                android:layout_width="match_parent"                                                                      
                android:layout_height="match_parent"                                                                     
                android:verticalSpacing="2dp"                                                                            
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"                                                                          
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"                                                  
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"                                                 
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"                                                     
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"                                                  
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"                                                                        
                android:numColumns="2"/>                                                                                                                                                           
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>                                                                  

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>                                                                    

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Reaz! Great edit!

Comment: Make sure you are using latest support library. Also this is a known usecase, did you try googling: 'coordinatorlayout swiperefresh' or something like this?

Comment: I googled it extensively. One of the good answers that I found was : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624138/android-coordinatorlayout-and-swiperefreshlayout which did not work in my case. I will try the latest support library since I am using 23.0.2 at the moment.

Answer (score -2):

meybe android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout  only support Linearlayout inside

my layout:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_main"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cat"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.activity.com.swiperfreshlayout.PullToRefreshScrollView>
```